# Using subset and max function in R

Tags: r

Using subset and max function, how to show the row in a dataframe having maximum amount in a particular column.
I have tried subset(x, subset=max(x$weight)) but its not working.

Comment: `subset(x,weight==max(weight))`(I rarely use `subset` though, personal taste. Prefer `[`) Perhaps you want `which.max`?

Comment: Thank you very much, finally i got the solution.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    slice(which.max(mpg))
```

Comment: Need to use subset and max function .

Comment: @Aalisha then the solution from the comment should work considering that there are NAs, `subset(x,weight==max(weight, na.rm = TRUE) & !is.na(weight))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets and logical operstor using selected column
Should look smth like codw below. However i am not sure about syntax. Wrote this on my phone

```
df[, df$column == max(df$column)]
```

Topic extension here
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: Really appreciated.